# How to change action key of android custom keyboard according to the text field?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm developing an android keyboard. I'm trying to use this method to change my custom keyboard action key, according to the text field that user selected. But this method is not working. Has there been any other way to change the action key?

```
public class MyKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements
        OnKeyboardActionListener {

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInputView(info, restarting);

        if(info.actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //Action Done
        }else if(info.actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
            //Action Search
        }else if(info.actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED){
            //Action Unspecified
        }

        //more code here
    }

}
```

Comment: You can change your current Keyboard at onStartInput method.

Comment: Yes, I can change current keyboard. But I can't track the action.

Comment: My suggestion is to you may check actionId in log.

Comment: or you may use 'info.imeOptions' here.

Comment: actionId is always equals to the, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED

Comment: I tried to use 'info.imeOptions' by adding a log. But it prints different different values for the same type of text fields. (Ex: I tried searching text fields in apps, it retusns different values) Do you have any idea how to use it? @NeetSoni

Comment: I used to detect this in my Keyboard class in setImeOptions method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this in Keyboard class.

```
    public class LatinKeyboard extends Keyboard {
         /**
         * This looks at the ime options given by the current editor, to set the
         * appropriate label on the keyboard's enter key (if it has one).
         */
        void setImeOptions(Resources res, int options) {

            switch (options&(EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION|EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION)) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO:
                   //Action GO
                   break;
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                   //Action Next
                   break;
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH:
                    //Action Search
                    break;
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND:
                    //Action SEND
                    break;
                default:
                    //Action Default
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

Here options is imeOptions from EditorInfo and I called this method in onStartInput.